# Filenotfound exception while reading confiration file in spring

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am trying to implement placeholder concept in spring  using netbeans IDE.
I want the properties file to be in the fodler where my jar will be deployed, so that it can be edited by the person running jar file.

The dist folder contains the jar file, libraries folder and a properties fiel containing entries related to datasource.

I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to read confiuration file and load into application context.
My configuration file has an entry as

```
<bean id="c12" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But i get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

****EDIT:****
Realised that the isssue is with classpath,
the classpath is the src folder when run in IDE and "jar file" when running jar on commandline, but in both cases it misses the properties file which is in same folder as jar . Other than specifying absolute path using file: is there any other way to counter with relative path in context to application

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the error message, without any indication, Spring tries to load if from your classpath. In your case, this means in your JAR.

If you want to load it from an file on the file system, you have to use the `file:` prefix. For instance to load it from the Java application launch path:

```
file:database.properties
```

But I would recommend to set an absolute path:

```
file:/path/to/database.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a database.properties file placed alongside your jar taking effect, you have to include the current directory into classpath when running the program

Assuming following directory structure:

```
myfolder
 +- myprog.jar
 +- database.properties
```

Your code should be able to pickup database.properties if the program is run using following command (with myfolder as current directory)

```
java -cp . -jar myprog.jar
```

Comment: I have tried running using java -cp . -jar myprog.jar, but i still get FILENotFoundException stating the fiel cannot be opened as it does not exist